# Select Case Within a Parsed Field

Tags: vb.net, parsing

I need to do a select case within a parser string. I need to select the second field (which works fine) then based on what that second field returns string wise, I need to switch it up a little bit, but for some reason its not quite working, I think I may not be binding it right to `r`, not sure.

```
                Dim r as DataRow
                Dim command = fields(1)
                Select Case command
                    Case 1
                        If fields(1) = "<Left Mouse Down> <Left Mouse Up> <Right Mouse Up>" Then
                            r("Mouse Command") = "Left Click"
                        End If

                    Case 2
                        If fields(1) = "<Right Mouse Down> <Left Mouse Up> <Right Mouse Up" Then
                            r("Mouse Command") = "Right click"
                        End If

                    Case 3
                        If fields(1) = "<Left Mouse Up> <Right Mouse Up>" & Microsoft.VisualBasic.LTrim("Scroll Wheel Roll") Then
                            r("Mouse Command") = "Scroll Wheel"
                        End If

                    Case 4
                        If fields(1) = Microsoft.VisualBasic.LTrim("<Left Mouse Up> <Right Mouse Up> <Press ") Then
                            r("Mouse Command") = "Key Press"
                        End If

                    Case 5
                        If fields(1) = "<Left Mouse Up> <Right Mouse Up>" Then
                            r("Mouse Command") = "Double Click"
                        End If

                End Select
```

**Solved**

Comment: Put a break on the Select Case and look at the various variables.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're accessing the wrong index of `field` somewhere. Either in the line `Dim command = fields(1)` or in the `If fields(1) = ...` statements.

`fields(1)` can not be both a number between 1 and 5 and also a string containing `Left Mouse Down ...`

Take your first case for instance:

```
Dim command = fields(1) '' You're accessing fields(1) here looking for an int
Select Case command
    Case 1
        If fields(1) = "..." '' and here, but looking for a string
...
```